# How to remove nbf claim

Tags: c#, json.net, jwt

have been looking an answer for this from everywhere, but can't seem to find one that applies to me. The thing is i'm trying to construct a JWT token with ASP.NET in c#. The problem i'm running in to is that somewhere it adds a "nbf" claim automatically to my claims and i can't seem to figure out how to remove it as the API host doesn't allow it in the token. Here's a code snipped of what creates the tokens:

```
               var plainTextSecurityKey = "key";
            var signingKey = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey(
                Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainTextSecurityKey));
            var signingCredentials = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SigningCredentials(signingKey,
                Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);


            var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>()
            {
                new Claim("iss", "smthing"),
                new Claim("sub", "smthing"),
                new Claim("iat", ToUnixTime(issued).ToString()),
                new Claim("exp",ToUnixTime(expire).ToString()),
                new Claim("aud", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new[] { "ohlc" }).ToString())
            });

 claimsIdentity.TryRemoveClaim(claimsIdentity.FindFirst("nbf"));


            var securityTokenDescriptor = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenDescriptor()
            {
                Subject = claimsIdentity,
                SigningCredentials = signingCredentials,
            };


            securityTokenDescriptor.NotBefore = null;

            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var plainToken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(securityTokenDescriptor);
            var signedAndEncodedToken = tokenHandler.WriteToken(plainToken);
```

I try to remove the nbf after forming the claimsIdentity, but it appears that it isn't added there.

Answer (score 22):

Try this:

```
tokenHandler.SetDefaultTimesOnTokenCreation = false
```

Reference: [System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/master/src/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/JwtSecurityTokenHandler.cs)

Comment: This helped me. I was getting `IDX12401: Expires: 'System.DateTime' must be after NotBefore: 'System.DateTime'.` before, but with SetDefaultTimesOnTokenCreation set to false, everything is fine. The main reason I want to omit `"nbf"` is that sometimes in tests we are overriding time in both token generation and validation.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get at it too early, the "nbf" claim is being added when you do this:

```
var plainToken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(securityTokenDescriptor);
```

After you create plainToken, you can remove claims you don't want on it, like this:

```
var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var plainToken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(securityTokenDescriptor);
plainToken.Payload.Remove("nbf");
var signedAndEncodedToken = tokenHandler.WriteToken(plainToken);
```